# Text border-bottom issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with text and I add a border-bottom but the bottom line width is equal with the text width, is there any way to make this bottom line to be much smaller than text? I want to be like in this image:

[image]

My code:

```css
.title-line {

border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-family: lato;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 0 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<dt class="title-line">My Text Example</dt>
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a pseudo element (like `::after`) instead of `border-bottom`.

```css
.title-line {
  position: relative; /* important for absolute child to work */
  font-family: lato;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
}


.title-line::after {
  content: ''; /* required to display pseudo elements */
  height: 1px; /* this works like a border-width */
  width: 10%; /* you can use a percentage of parent or fixed px value */
  background: #CCC; /* the color of border */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; /* position it at the bottom of parent */
  margin: 0 auto; left: 0; right: 0; /* horizontal centering */
}
```

```html
<dt class="title-line">My Text Example</dt>
```

Comment: thank you, but I have a problem, there can be more texts, and I can't use position: absolute for :after, is there any way?

Comment: @RobertD Aziz's CSS should work for any text with the class `title-line` applied to it. And why can't you use absolute positioning for :after?

Comment: yes indeed, sorry for this was my mistake, because I add in the :after top:10%. Aziz answer is perfect, thank yo so much Aziz